# vue.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier has already been declared

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two demos for same library under [repo](https://github.com/MoYummy/vue-top-down/tree/master/example), with [demo](https://moyummy.github.io/vue-top-down/example/).

The main difference is that, one is for `browser` use and the other is for `node` use.

However `browser` one will have error

```
index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'HeaderComp' has already been declared
```

What is the main cause?

**Update:**

1. Please keep in mind I do not declare a variable twice! I also tried to add console log at the top to ensure the script is executed once!

   ```
   var HeaderComp = {
     name: 'HeaderComp',
     template: `
     Back
     {{ r.title }}
   `,
     mixins: [VueTopDown.VueTopDownItem],
     computed: {
       routes () {
         return [
           { href: '/page', title: 'Page' },
           { href: '/hello-vue', title: 'HelloVue' }
         ]
       }
     }
   }

   var FooterComp = {
     name: 'FooterComp',
     template: `{{ vueFooter }}`,
     mixins: [VueTopDown.VueTopDownItem],
     data () {
       return {
         vueFooter: 'This is Vue Footer'
       }
     }
   }

   var ContentComp = {
     name: 'ContentComp',
     template: ``,
     mixins: [VueTopDown.VueTopDownItem],
     computed: {
       innerHTML () {
         var root = document.createElement('div')
         root.innerHTML = this[VTDConstants.OUTER_HTML]
         return root.querySelector('*').innerHTML
       }
     }
   }

   var HelloVue = {
     template: `Hello Vue`,
     props: ['clazz'],
     inheritAttrs: false
   }

   var Page = {
     template: ``,
     props: ['clazz', 'innerHTML'],
     inheritAttrs: false
   }

   var router = new VueRouter([
     { path: '/hello-vue', component: HelloVue },
     { path: '/page', component: Page },
     { path: '*', redirect: '/page' }
   ])

   var inst = new Vue({
     router,
     mixins: [VueTopDown.VueTopDown],
     components: {
       HeaderComp: HeaderComp,
       FooterComp,
       ContentComp
     },
     data () {
       return {
         [VueTopDown.VTDConstants]: {
           'header': HeaderComp,
           'footer': FooterComp,
           '.content': ContentComp
         }
       }
     }
   })

   inst.$mount('#app')
   ```
2. Also keep in mind that similar code works fine in `node` environment but fails in `browser`!
3. Doesn't occur if commenting out `inst.$mount('#app')`

**Expect**

The expected behavior of `browser` should be same as that of `node`.

Comment: I casted a reopen vote. OP is right here. The error message is apparently out of nowhere, caused by vue.js. Somehow it redeclares the contents of the files, somewhere.

Comment: use `var` as a workaround, instead of `const` or `let`

Comment: @Adelin I am afraid this cannot be a workaround. It will run into endless calls. Maybe it is an issue in `vue` or my use of custom rendering is incorrect. I have submitted a topic in official forum to consult `vue` core team for support.

Comment: Ok but just so you know, stopping an endless call with let or const is not a solution either.

Comment: Sure, `vue` code cannot take effect without `$mount`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `VueTopDown` but as a first guess, that's where I'd look. Does that mixin redeclare components passed into it? Maybe swap the order of `HeaderComp` and `FooterComp` to see if the error then migrates to the latter component. That would at least tell you if it's something unique to `HeaderComp`.

Comment: Somehow swapping `let` to `var` fixed a similar issue I am having, but I do not understand why.

Comment: I had this same issue. The div that I was targetting to mount my app didn't have a closing tag.